# Is syllabification significant in (natural) spoken languages?

Tags: pronunciation, syllables

The way I understand/guess it, it's not significant in English, that is, there's no example where a word changes meaning by how it is broken into syllables. I guess and ask because there are different opinions on whether a word like "very" is to be syllabified as "ver-y" or "ve-ry". If this mattered in the spoken language, the pronunciation ought to be different and would therefore settle this.

Is this true for every natural language, or are there language(s) where it matters how a word is broken into syllables? In that case, how do you tell syllables apart (in spoken language)? I would prefer examples in languages as closely related to English as possible if any exist.

Comment: Not sure if it counts as being ‘significant’, but in Danish, syllabification is generally taken as the main factor in how border consonants (i.e., consonants that separate word-internal syllables σ1 and σ2) are pronounced. Syllabification is based on the reduction of the vowel in σ2: if reduced, syllabify as _late_ as possible, otherwise as _early_ as possible: for example, (archaic) _rata_ ‘rate’ has full /a/ in σ2, yielding /raː.ta/ [ˈʁɑːtˢʰæ]; while (normal) _rate_ has reduced /ə/ in σ2, yielding /raːt.ə/ [ˈʁɑːd̥ə/.

Comment: There is blurry syllabification and ambisyllabicity in English. Well explained here: https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/hayes/120a/HayesAmbisyllabicity.pdf Not everyone agrees on how a word is analyzed in syllables.

Comment: What about English, RP: _see Zion_ [siː.zaɪ.ən] vs. _sees iron_ [siːz.aɪ.ən]? It took me about a couple of minutes to come up with this one, and I'm sure many more of those are possible in English alone.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Interresting, do you have a more "modern" example? I didn't find those words on wiktionary.

Comment: @YellowSky Yes, but that's more of word boundary, but even there the same question could be relevant. Do you hear the difference between "see Zion" and "sees iron"? And if that's the case, why (ie where's the actual difference)?

Comment: @skyking There is a _very_ heavy tendency towards vowel reduction in Danish, so there are far more words that match _rate_ than _rata_. There are still lots of instances of unreduced vowels, but I’m having trouble thinking of minimal pairs. One example (which is odd and irregular) is the suffix _-isk_ ‘-ish’, which sometimes acts as reduced and sometimes not, even in etymologically related contexts: _logisk_ ‘logical’ is unreduced /ˈloːˀ.ɡisk/ [ˈloː.ɡ̊isɡ̊], while suffixal _-ologisk_ ‘-ological’ (‘biological’, etc.) is reduced /oˈloːˀg.isk/ [oˈloːˀ.isɡ̊].

Comment: Perhaps a better example is comparing forms of the same root by different derivational suffixes where one has a reduced vowel and the other an unreduced one, for example _-isk_ ‘-ish’ (as above, most commonly reduced) vs _-isere_ ‘-ise’ (unreduced). A word like _automat_ ‘automat, vending machine’ is /aʊtoˈmaːˀt/ [aʊ.tˢʰo.ˈmɛ̝ːˀd̥], _automatisk_ ‘automatic’ is /aʊtoˈmaːˀtisk/ [aʊ.tˢʰo.ˈmɛ̝ːˀd̥.isg̊], but _automatisere_ ‘automate’ is /aʊtomatiˈseːˀrə/ [aʊ.tˢʰo.ˈmæ.tˢʰi.ˈse̝ːˀ.ɐ].

Comment: Languages are spoken first. Breaking words into syllables comes second...

Answer (score 6):

[It's famously been claimed](http://www.lingref.com/cpp/wccfl/25/paper1442.pdf) that syllabification is contrastive in Blackfoot, with near-minimal pairs like *i.stawáʔsiwḁ* "he grew" and *ɪs.tatánsiwḁ* "he bragged", or *ipi.ksit* "flee" and *ipik.ksit* "be anxious", distinguished primarily by syllable boundaries.

But this can also be analyzed as contrastive length within consonant clusters, or "contrastive mora assignment", which is what Elfner is really arguing for.

Comment: Magic?! I'm going to be really ticked if this doesn't receive the green checkmark!

Comment: @Fomalhaut I've not really digested this answer yet, but I will likely accept it.